# animating elements when you scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I am trying to add animations to elements that are only viewable after the scroll down has taken place, how do I ensure that the animations have only taken place AFTER the user has scrolled down and can view them. Preferably using CSS and not Javascript.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/how-to-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling --> How to check if element is visible after scrolling?

Comment: AFAIK there is not direct way to condition CSS styling to the scrolling in a page. This might be relevant though https://css-tricks.com/styling-based-on-scroll-position/

Comment: Sounds as though intersectionObserver would be helpful here, though it needs a bit (not much) of Javascript. If you put up some code to show your specific case it would help.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't do it without javascipt.**

you can use IntersectionObserver to do that. It's mostly used for lazy loading but
you will need a small piece of to be able to observe your scroll.

```
var sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');

var options = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 0.25
}

var callback = (entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
      var target = entry.target;
      console.log(target);
    if (entry.intersectionRatio >= 0.25) {
      target.classList.add("is-inview");
    } else {
      target.classList.remove("is-inview");
    }
  })
}

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options)
sections.forEach((section, index) => {
  observer.observe(section)
});
```

you can see smallest working code [here](https://imjignesh.com/how-to-trigger-css-animation-on-scroll/).